# onblur="function(this)" is not working for multiple dynamically created textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've three textboxes. which are included retail price, quantity and total amount. whenever i enter retail price and quantity in textboxes then there should be automatically multiply retail price and quantity's values and save into the total amount textbox. Problem is that My code works only for one time, but when added Dynamically textboxes then onblur="cal(this)" not work. i want that single onblur="cal(this)" function work for multiple time. give the solution.

#### Bootstrap 3 form

```
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
   onblur="cal(this)" onkeypress='validate(event)' placeholder="Quantity"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="retail_price" 
     readonly="true" onkeypress='validate(event)' id="retail_price" 
  onblur="cal(this)" placeholder="Retail Price" />
</td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" readonly="true" class="form-control" name="amount" 
    id="amount" placeholder="Total Amount" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
  </td>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function cal(_input)
{
    var first = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('retail_price').value; 
    document.getElementById('amount').value = parseFloat(parseInt(first)*parseInt(second)).toFixed(3);

   }
```

Comment: I've tried it and it's working. Maybe the error is in the part you say "when added Dynamically textboxes" 
Could you add how you're adding dinamically textboxes ?

Comment: you do not even use `_input`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem mainly is your javascript looks for elements by id, so what it gets is the first element on DOM with that Id. Indeed, is working and is operating over the first elements with those Ids.

It is not a good pattern to repeat ids on document elements. Even that, you should be looking for the sibling elements onblur instead of those with a fixed id.

Maybe will be a better code using `querySelector` with some css selector by class name, like adding a class on those elements, so you can use it to style over all the elements on that document too or if you keep it like this use an attribute selector

```js
function cal(_input)
{
  const thisIsTD = _input.parentElement;
  const thisIsTR = thisIsTD.parentElement;


    var first = thisIsTR.querySelector('[name=quantity]').value;
    var second = thisIsTR.querySelector('[name=retail_price]').value; 
    thisIsTR.querySelector('[name=amount]').value = parseFloat(parseInt(first)*parseInt(second)).toFixed(3);

   }
   
 function validate(event){ return true; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
   onblur="cal(this)" onkeypress='validate(event)' placeholder="Quantity"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="retail_price" 
      onkeypress='validate(event)' id="retail_price" 
  onblur="cal(this)" placeholder="Retail Price" />
</td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" readonly="true" class="form-control" name="amount" 
    id="amount" placeholder="Total Amount" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
   onblur="cal(this)" onkeypress='validate(event)' placeholder="Quantity"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="retail_price" 
      onkeypress='validate(event)' id="retail_price" 
  onblur="cal(this)" placeholder="Retail Price" />
</td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" readonly="true" class="form-control" name="amount" 
    id="amount" placeholder="Total Amount" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

"If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a document." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Query selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

@jmtalarn gave the correct answer, I just wanted to show how to do work with DOM

Since, when changing the layout, you will have to change the code, and this can be avoided using the function `findAncestor`.

```js
function findAncestor(el, sel) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel)));
    return el;
}

function cal(intputElement)
{
  let row = findAncestor(intputElement, 'tr');

  let first = row.querySelector('[name=quantity]').value;
  let second = row.querySelector('[name=retail_price]').value; 
  
  let result = parseFloat(parseInt(first)*parseInt(second));
  
  if(result){
    row.querySelector('[name=amount]').value = result.toFixed(3);
  } else {
    // show error
  }
}
   
function validate(event){ return true; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
   onblur="cal(this)" onkeypress='validate(event)' placeholder="Quantity"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="retail_price" 
      onkeypress='validate(event)' id="retail_price" 
  onblur="cal(this)" placeholder="Retail Price" />
</td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" readonly="true" class="form-control" name="amount" 
    id="amount" placeholder="Total Amount" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" 
   onblur="cal(this)" onkeypress='validate(event)' placeholder="Quantity"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="retail_price" 
      onkeypress='validate(event)' id="retail_price" 
  onblur="cal(this)" placeholder="Retail Price" />
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" readonly="true" class="form-control" name="amount" 
    id="amount" placeholder="Total Amount" onkeypress='validate(event)' />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```